# Node get request displays empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection on mongoDB with a set of data in it. When I attempt to make a get request in my node code to send the data so I can see it is actually being get, all that is displayed is an empty array.

Server.js code:

```
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Post = require("./models/post")

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@<mongohost>/posts?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true},
    (req, res) => {
        console.log("Connected to database")
    })


app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    Post.find()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch((err)=> {
        console.log(err)
    })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("express server is running on port " + port)
})
```

Post.js code (schema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const postSchema = new Schema ({
    _id: Number, 
    profilePic: String,
    locationData: String,
    authorName : String,
    postImg : String,
    filler : String,
    likes: Number,
    commentAuthors: [{type: String}],
    comments: [{type: String}],
    timestamp: Number
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
module.exports = Post
```

Comment: Just to make sure, the collection called "posts" and is in the database also called "posts" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.lean()` to get a plan javascript object instead of a query object. Also, since you're sending json, use `res.json()` instead of `res.send()`

Modify your code like:

```
Post.find().lean()
    .then((result) => {
        res.json(result)
    })
    .catch((err)=> {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Found out the issue. I added the name of the collection the data is in, inside the model declaration. I also used your code and it helped. Thank you!